# How can I distinguish between a person being humorous and non-humorous?

Tags: conflicts, humor, acquaintances

I have a situation where a person is telling many jokes, but the problem is it is hard to tell when they are serious. How should this situation be handled?

They are an acquaintance that I work with. (This question is not on The Workplace as this is a more interpersonal issue.)

Comment: What makes it delicate? Can you please flesh-out your question a bit more?

Comment: @Catija it ends up less delicate then I thought

Comment: You discovered this in three minutes?

Comment: A context would be useful. It's very different how we would relate to a neighbour to a family member to an acquaintance

Comment: @Catija it was partially a type and a realization how dumb i was

Comment: It is best to go light on details as they scan the internet for mentions of them and people have gotten fired over issues and comments on the internet. I would rather not risk anything yet

Comment: @Christopher I totally get it that's why I suggested fudging it - say it's a neighbour

Comment: Related question: https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/16/102.

Comment: I'm tempted to vote to close as too broad; I think you really should explain the situation in more detail. It certainly can't hurt.

Comment: @hde well I have a answer that helped and I really can't. The more I give the more likely the company I work for finds out. Idk how bad I can be but it can get me fired

Comment: I'm not too sure why providing an example can get you fired - any example I can think about seems harmless, but if you can please provide a similar situation example. As for the current form, I still don't see this as too broad - already limited to **acquaintances** at work, however an example will be helpful to further refine the answers to your situation.

Comment: Are these jokes related to **racism, sexism, or something potentially offensive to anyone**? Vegetarianism? Or is this just about **unfunny jokes** where you have problem on how to respond?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can always simply ask.  I have had very good luck with, **"Wait, I can't tell if you're being serious right now."**  Most people will immediately let you know, problem solved.

If the person systematically continues to give sarcastic answers to this question, usually there is something else going on.  There may be anger issues, avoidance issues, or social stresses causing the behavior.  Depending on the situation, you can again level with them.

In the most extreme cases, something is seriously wrong, and you may have to decide whether you enjoy being around this person or not.  *It is not your responsibility to fix anyone, but they often appreciate the company.*

Good luck, friend!

Comment: As a person who likes to joke with serious face, I can say that it's indeed valid to just ask.

Comment: @Alissa indeed I am the same. I have a very dry sense of humour and often confuse people